# Creating a label from two attribute table column titles with a space between them

Tags: qgis, expression

What expression do I need so that I'd have a space between two attribute columns titles in QGIS' Label expression dialogue?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It should be

```
"First field" || ' ' || "Second field"
```

|| is string concatenation operator. Use Single quotes for Space, Double Quotes are for Field.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the expression below to concatenate two column values
[image]